# Intel I219-V NIC does not work properly under Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, network-interface, intel

I got a new Lenovo T14 Gen2 on which I run a Fedora 34 beta. The notebook has a built-in Intel I219-V Ethernet NIC, which seems to work not properly. Every time I try to use Ethernet the NIC has severe packetloss / slow speeds (both in dock and without). To preclude a hardware bug, I installed Windows, where the NIC runs without any problems. The problems only occur when I use Fedora 33 or 34 beta. I also tried different kernels up to 5.11.16-300 without any success. The Intel e1000e driver for the NIC seems to work without any problems.

Comment: This is probably most useful as a report to Lenovo at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Fedora/bd-p/lx04_en. I know the ThinkPad team monitors that forum for issues.

Comment: Any solutions? I find that the micro ethernet adaptor works, but the RJ45 does not.